# How to remove event listener from anonymous function without naming it?

Tags: javascript

I need to remove event listener from a function.
I've searched here and google but all solutions I found were about make a reference or give name to each function created, but my function is created within a loop so it doesn't work:

```
for(let i = 0; i < boxSelected.length; i++){
    boxSelected[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
      // my code here
```

Is there a way to add the event listener to each element created inside loop and distinguish between them later?

or

Can I remove the event listener without need to name it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`removeEventListener` requires you pass reference to function not its name.

So once you save function itself into any variable(say, array or object with linking to index) you will be able to remove it later.

Also you can put single listener on common parent node and disable/enable processing for specific elements by changing some their attribute